# batch command line script for outputting files with same name as input file

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

This has been driving me crazy for a while now and I've never been able to properly figure it out. I can't get a loop, or a batch of multiple files to do a command and then have them outputted with the inputted filename but changed slightly.

It's very simple I know but I can't figure it out.

Easiest example is converting audio files. I have hundreds if not thousands I want to convert the exact same way at the same time.

Using sox.exe as an example I want to convdert all the 24bit FLAC files in a folder to 16bit wav files...the single file command for this is:
sox.exe [inputfile] -b 16 [outputfile] rate 44100 dither -s

Using *.flac seems to work fine for the input but the output never seems to work correctly. Can someone show me the proper code for creating a loop in this case...is it using the for /f command or something like that?

I'll take either a script I run every time or a script that I can put into a batch file named convert.bat that I can then just drag and drop a folder or all the files onto it that I want to process.

...something like
for i in *.flac; sox.exe "$i" -b 16 "$i.wav" rate 44100 dither -s; done

Thanks

Comment: With the flac directory current, `for %i in (*.flac) do "X:\path\to\sox.exe" "%i" "X:\destination\%~ni.wav"`. Just add your required options.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, a for loop.

```
for %%i in (*.flac) do (
  converter.exe %%i
)
:: Use %i if you're in Command Prompt.
```

Answer (score 0):

as you (probably) want one outputfile per inputfile (not one single outputfile for all your thousands of inputfiles), you have to execute your application for each single inputfile. Gladly, `cmd` provides a simple solution for "do the same thing for every file":

```
for %%A in (*.flac) do (
  sox.exe "%%A" -b 16 "%%~nA.wav" rate 44100 dither -s
)
```

`%%A` represents one inputfile at a time. You can use modifiers to address the different parts of the filename (see `for /?`), for example `%%~nA` gives you the name only (no drive, no folder, no extension). If needed, you can use a mixed string with `"%%~dA\output folder\%%~nA.wav"` (use the same drive letter as the input file, an hardcoded special folder, the name of the inputfile and a hardcoded extension.